# Mass Probability function of minimum of random independent variables X,Y with Geometric Distribution of parameter p.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For $X\sim \textrm{Geo}(p)$ we have that $f_{X}(x)=p(1-p)^x$ for $x=0,1,2,...$ and $f_{X}(x)=0$ otherwise. There is a way to solve this question in literally one line using the fact that $P(X\ge x)=(1-p)^x$ for $x=0,1,2,...$ . But my first instinct to solve this was different and want to understand what am I doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

So here's my attempt: Let $Z=\min(X,Y)$. Since $X,Y\ge 0 \implies Z\ge 0$. We are looking for $P(Z=z)$. For $z<0$ we have that $P(Z=z)=0$. For $z\ge 0$:
$$\begin{aligned}P(Z=z)&=P(X=z,Y\ge z)+P(Y=z,X>z)=\\
&=P(X=z)P(Y\ge z)+P(Y=z)P(X>z)\end{aligned}$$
since $X,Y$ are independent. Now for $z=0$ we can conclude that $P(Z=0)=2p-p^2$. For $z\ge 1$ :
$$\begin{aligned}P(Z=z)&=P(X=z)P(Y\ge z)+P(Y=z)P(X\ge z-1)=\\
&=p(1-p)^z(1-p)^z+p(1-p)^z(1-p)^{z-1}=\\
&=(2p-p^2)(1-p)^{2z-1}\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your approach: we have
$$\{\min(X,Y)=z\}=\{X=z,Y>z\}\cup\{X>z,Y=z\}\cup\{X=z,Y=z\}$$
So, by independence,
$$\begin{aligned}P(\min(X,Y)=z)&=P(X=z)P(Y>z)+P(X>z)P(Y=z)+P(X=z)P(Y=z)=\\
&=2(1-p)^zp(1-p)^{z+1}+p^2(1-p)^{2z}=\\
&=2p(1-p)^{2z+1}+p^2(1-p)^{2z}=\\
&=(1-p)^{2z}(2p(1-p)+p^2)=\\
&=(1-p)^{2z}(2p-p^2)=\\
&=(1-p)^{2z}(1-(1-p)^2)=\\
&=(1-(1-(1-p)^2))^z((1-(1-p)^2)=\\
&=(1-q)^zq
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Yes, I've solved it this way as well, but cannot understand why if we conclude the case $X=Y=z$ in one of the other two disjoint sets, we do not conclude the correct result. In other words, where is the mistake in my attempt above.

Comment: @GaloisTH Note $P(X>z)=1-P(X\leq z)=1-(1-(1-p)^{z+1})=(1-p)^{z+1}$. We get 
$$p(1-p)^z((1-p)^z+(1-p)^{z+1})=p(1-p)^{2z}(1+(1-p))=(1-p)^{2z}(2p-p^2)$$

Comment: So where is the mistake saying for $z\ge 1$, $P(X>z)=P(X\ge z-1)=(1-p)^{z-1}$, since $P(X\ge x)=(1-p)^x$ for $x=0,1,2....$ ?

Comment: @GaloisTH Note $P(X>z)=P(X\geq z+1)=1-P(X\leq z)$

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Silly mistake of mine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GaloisTH leave an upvote and accept if you appreciated the answer! :)